# How to convert rows to columns with conditions?

Tags: mysql

I am accessing a WordPress database and I want to convert the rows to columns when I make a selection. That works so far but I don't know how to specify conditions.

**Table wp_usermeta**

```
| umeta_id | user_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| - | - | - | - |
| 1 | 1 | first_name | james |
| 2 | 1 | last_name | wilson |
| 3 | 1 | zip | 83902 |
| 4 | 2 | first_name | mason |
| 5 | 2 | last_name | burton |
| 6 | 2 | zip | 29483 |
| 7 | 3 | first_name | jackson |
| 8 | 3 | last_name | owen |
| 9 | 3 | zip |  |
```

**Table wp_users**

```
| ID | user_email |
| - | - |
| 1 | james.wilson@example.com |
| 2 | mason.burton@example.com |
| 3 | jackson.owen@example.com |
```

```
select
user_id,
max(case when meta_key = 'first_name' then meta_value end) first_name,
max(case when meta_key = 'last_name' then meta_value end) last_name,
max(case when meta_key = 'zip' then meta_value end) postal_code,
user_email as email
from `wp_usermeta`
left join `wp_users` on `wp_usermeta`.`user_id` = `wp_users`.`ID`
group by `user_id`;
```

**Result**

```
| user_id | first_name | last_name | postal_code| email |
| - | - | - | - | - |
| 1 | james | wilson | 83902 | james.wilson@example.com |
| 2 | mason | burton | 29483 | mason.burton@example.com |
| 3 | jackson | owen | null | jackson.owen@example.com |
```

I need conditions like this:

```
where zip/postal_code is not null
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'postal_code' in 'where clause'

case when meta_value = 'james' then 'good' else 'bad' end
Error Code: 1055. Expression #5 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'wp_usermeta.meta_value' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: After the GROUP BY clause ... `HAVING postal_code IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Thank you that works. But I still need the second condition. The topic has been closed although there is still an open question.

Comment: Hard to comment because your SQL does not contain that expression.  It's tough to understand what you intended.  This could be what you wanted, in the SELECT list: `, CASE WHEN MAX(meta_value) = 'james' THEN 'good' ELSE 'bad' END` ... Note, this logic is probably not complete.  Just a guess.

Comment: or maybe: `max(case when meta_key = 'first_name' AND meta_value = 'james' then 'good' ELSE 'bad' end)` ... Still, check the suggested link to the basic solution to your initial question.  If you have a more specific / different question, ask just that in a new posting, if you can't find another similar question / answer already in SO.

Comment: Great, the second one worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @dever asking multiple questions in a post is explicitly off topic - there is a close reason for those. rather than closing the question down as needs more focus, I gave you a duplicate. Please, check out the help center on close reasons: https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: @jon-armstrong The second one does not work. I tried this before. max always selects the max. In this case 'good'.

Comment: You may have misunderstood the suggestion.  1. Always show your attempt that you say failed.  2. It helps to provide all the SQL required to duplicate your test.  Here's an example of a functional / successful test case: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef1999c9b44b86fc47dc9af8eda12ad8)